# Acumatica Generic Endpoint Screen ID Generation Error

Tags: generics, screen, acumatica, endpoint

When creating a new Generic Inquiry in Acumatica (2018 R1 18.108.0016) by

1. Enter Inquiry Title
2. Enter Site Map Title
3. Select "hidden" (others fail also) as Site Map Location
4. Click SAVE

I always get a popup error message

[image: Error Message]

then I hit "OK" and it generates a seemingly random ScreenID "GIFR0202". Everything seems to work fine from there on.

Unfortunately, this ScreenID "GIFR0202" will cause a problem on my Production System since there is one there already under that name. To preemptively address this issue, I manually changed the ScreenID to "GIJS0100" using the Customization->SiteMap. Doing this comes with a warning like "Changing the ScreenID may have extended consequences". Performing the change works nice, since subsequent Generic Inquiries I create are increments of this ScreenID.

Is this going to cause me any headaches when exporting the package, importing into a Production Site, and Publishing?

I would rather not "just try" this, to answer my question, as I am not the primary developer on this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds more like a glitch than a bug. The error is coming from modern UI site map integration. MUI Sub Category being a table that holds sitemap categories. The record key indicates it's one of the stock category 'Inquiries' that ships with the product. You could upgrade Acumatica to see if it resolves the error. Alternatively, I would think deleting the record might get rid of the error as it won't try to insert duplicate but I can't guarantee there would be no side effects. I suggest to test it and forget about it if the customization works fine.

[image]